# sort objects by a property values

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have some objects in an array and want to have them sorted. The objects should be sorted by a metric value. So I have the following function:

```
    objectz.sort(function(a,b){
        return b.metric - a.metric;
    }
```

The problem is that some objects have the same property values and the results of the sorting are always different.I want to additionally sort the objects with the same metric value by their name property so I get the same order of objects every time I sort them.

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
objectz.sort(function(a,b){
    var result = b.metric - a.metric;
    if (!result) return a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1;
    return result;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to zerkms:

```
objectz.sort(function(a,b) {
    var x = b.metric - a.metric; 
    return x || b.name - a.name;
});
```

Seems to be a reverse sort (higher values occur first), is that what you want?

#### Edit

Note that the `-` operator is only suitable if the value of 'name' can be converted to a number. Otherwise, use `<` or `>`. The sort function should deal with a.name == b.name, which the `>` opertator on its own won't do, so you need something like:

```
objectz.sort(function(a,b) {
    var x = b.metric - a.metric; 

    // If b.metric == a.metric
    if (!x) {

      if (b.name == a.name) {
        x = 0;

      else if (b.name < a.name) {
        x = 1;

      else {
        x = -1;
      }
    }
    return x;
});
```

which can be made more concise:

```
objectz.sort(function(a,b) {
    var x = b.metric - a.metric; 

    if (!x) {
      x = (b.name == a.name)? 0 : (b.name < a.name)? 1 : -1;
    }
    return x;
});
```

Given that the `metric` comparison seems to be largest to smallest order, then the ternary exrpession should be:

```
      x = (b.name == a.name)? 0 : (b.name < a.name)? -1 : 1;
```

if it is required that say Zelda comes before Ann. Also, the value of `name` should be reduced to all lower case (or all upper case), otherwise 'zelda' and 'Ann' will be sorted in the opposite order to 'Zelda' and 'ann'

Comment: Excatly the same as `b.metric - a.metric`. The `-` operator will convert both sides to numbers first, wheras the '<' operator will not and uses a different algorithm for strings and numbers. So `'02' < '1'` is true, but `'02' - '1'` returns `1`. It depends on the values and how the OP wants them treated.

Comment: `'a' - 'b'` returns `NaN` for me. I assume `name` property stores *strings*

Comment: Yes, if `name` can't be converted to a number it returns NaN. Will add a comment.

Comment: `(b.name == a.name)? 0` is pointless, as long as you don't have other criterias - you can return `1` or `-1` and this will not change anything

Comment: According to [ECMA-262 §15.4.4.11](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.11) the comparison function "should be a function that accepts two arguments x and y and returns a negative value if x < y, zero if x = y, or a positive value if x > y". Whether returning zero for *x = y* matters or not in this case I don't know. To me, it should be included unless there is a good reason not to and is consistent with returning *x - y* for numbers.