# Sort a javascript array of objects by object property

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sort an array.  For instance, given array a (below), I would like to return array b.

I know I can do `a.sort()`, however, I don't want to sort on the actual array element, but on a property (s for this example) of the array element.  How can this be accomplished?

Thank you

```
var a=[
  {s:"ced",o:{obj:1}},
  {s:"cde",o:{obj:2}},
  {s:"ade",o:{obj:3}},
  {s:"bde",o:{obj:4}}
]

var b=[
  {s:"ade",o:{obj:3}},
  {s:"bde",o:{obj:4}},
  {s:"cde",o:{obj:2}},
  {s:"ced",o:{obj:1}}
]
```

Comment: Duplicates: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900732/javascript-sort-objects-in-an-array-alphabetically-on-one-property-of-the-arra) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966247/sort-objects-by-a-property-values)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Array.prototype.sort` accepts an optional parameter: a callback telling it how to sort.

```
a.sort(function(x,y) {
    // do something here
    // return -1 if x < y
    // return  1 if x > y
    // otherwise, return 0
});
```

So, in your case, it would be:

```
a.sort(function(x,y) {return x.s == y.s ? 0 : (x.s < y.s ? -1 : 1);});
```

Comment: Thanks Kolink.  What is x and y?  For instance, is x the current item and y the highest or lowest?

Comment: They are two items from the array, picked by the `sort` function to try and work out what order they go in. for example, if the input array is `[2,3,1]` then it might ask "what order do 2 and 3 go in?"... "what about 2 and 1?"... before getting to "okay, I got it, it's `[1,2,3]`." The point is you don't need to know *which* items they are, all you need to know is that they are two items and you are being asked how to compare them.

Answer (score 1):

The [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method accepts a *compareFunction* parameter, where you can define how to calculate sort order.
As you want to compare strings this function should use [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2167619/1615483).
One way to create a sorting function which can be quickly adjusted is to generate it via another function. This means you can create sort functions automatically for any property of an object.
Put the two to together and you get..

```
function genSortFn(prop){
    return function(a,b){ return a[prop].localeCompare( b[prop] ); };
}
a.sort( genSortFn('s') );
b.sort( genSortFn('s') );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.s < b.s){
        return -1;
    }
    if(a.s > b.s){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lbstr/nCKpG/